# neo4j - Create relationships between all nodes in database (Out of memory)

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a neo4j database with ~260000 *(EDIT: Incorrect by order of magnitude previously, missing 0)* nodes of genes, something along the lines of:

- example_nodes: `sourceId`, `targetId`
- with an index on both `sourceId` and `targetId`

I am trying to build the relationships between all the nodes but am constantly running into OOM issues. I've increased my JVM heap size to `-Xmx4096m` and `dbms.memory.pagecache.size=16g` on a system with 16G of RAM.

I am assuming I need to optimize my query because it simply cannot complete in any of its current forms. However, I have tried the following three to no avail:

`MATCH (start:example_nodes),(end:example_nodes) WHERE start.targetId = end.sourceId CREATE (start)-[r:CONNECT]->(end) RETURN r`

(on a subset of the 5000 nodes, this query above completes in only a matter of seconds. It does of course warn: This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.)

`MATCH (start:example_nodes) WITH start MATCH (end:example_nodes) WHERE start.targetId = end.sourceId CREATE (start)-[r:CONNECT]->(end) RETURN r`

`OPTIONAL MATCH (start:example_nodes) WITH start MATCH (end:example_nodes) WHERE start.targetId = end.sourceId CREATE (start)-[r:CONNECT]->(end) RETURN r`

Any ideas how this query could be optimized to succeed would be much appreciated.

--

**Edit**

In a lot of ways I feel that while the apoc libary does indeed solve the memory issues, the function could be optimized if it were to run along the lines of this incredibly simple pseudocode:

```
for each start_gene
create relationship to end_gene where start_gene.targetId = end_gene.source_id
move on to next once relationship has been created
```

But I am unsure how to achieve this in cypher.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [apoc](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) library for batching.

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
MATCH (start:example_nodes),(end:example_nodes) WHERE not (start)-[:CONNECT]->(end) and id(start) > id(end) AND start.targetId = 
end.sourceId 
with start,end limit {limit}
CREATE (start)-[:CONNECT]->(end) 
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:5000})
```

Comment: Ah that is good to know, and it appears to be helping with the memory issue, but now the query has been running for an incredibly long time (3hr+) with no end in sight. I was thinking, since each node only represents one relationship, is there a way to proceed to adding the next relationship once the match has been created? Thus there should only be `n` operations vs `n*(n-1)/2` no?

Comment: yea should not take that long for 25k nodes... I added the `WHERE id(start) <> id(end)`... maybe that is a problem, because in any cartesian product I had to define that is not the same node ... so it maybe falls into some weird loop... also the sequence of filters influence the query time, so you can play around with `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN` to find the best combination

Comment: also maybe 16gb pagecache more than needed for 25k nodes and you can upgrade the heap size instead

Comment: Thank you - it definitely does seem to be in some kind of loop, because running `MATCH (n:example_nodes)-[:CONNECT]->() RETURN COUNT(n)` is already at `89000` and continually increasing. There should only be `25000` relationships by the end of the operation if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: You'll want `WHERE id(start) < id(end)` to avoid having two relationships per pair (one in each direction), and this will also prevent creating the relationship from nodes to themselves.